# How to expand $2^6 \cos^7(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How to expand $2^6 \cos^7(x)$

The answer is $\cos(7x) +7\cos(5x) +21\cos(3x) +35\cos(x)$.

Comment: Is not it following on using de moivre identity to expand $\cos^7x$.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae)

Comment: They may have mistyped the problem statement, it would have worked with $2^\color{red}{6}\cos^7 x$.

Comment: Ye you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2\cos{(nx)}=e^{inx}+e^{-inx}$$
$$(2\cos{(x)})^7=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^7$$
$$=(e^{i7x}+e^{-i7x})+7(e^{i5x}+e^{-i5x})+21(e^{i3x}+e^{-i3x})+35(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$$
$$=2\cos{(7x)}+14\cos{(5x)}+42\cos{(3x)}+70\cos{(x)}$$

Comment: Sorry but can u please tell me how to expand $(e^ix+e^-ix)^7

Comment: $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}$ it's called binomial expansion.

Comment: Ye I made a mistake by typing 2^7, it was actually 2^6